# Pull single file from master

Tags: git, version-control

I'm looking for a solution for a problem I'm trying to solve.
I have a monorepo which has a file in the main branch that is getting updated in every merge to the main branch.
I want the other branches (which are likely behind the main branch) to have the exact version of that file in the main branch.
My question is: Is there a way to pull a single file from main to other branches?
And if so, is there a way to make that process automatic?

I use bitbucket as SCM and VSCode to commit/pull/push.

Comment: Git doesn't pull files. It pulls commits, which are snapshots of the entire repo.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution.
`git fetch --all`,
 followed by
`git checkout origin/master -- path/to/file`

Comment: This still gets all the files you don't want, it just doesn't put them into the working directory.

Comment: @evolutionxbox What are the consequences of that action, besides get the file I needed? 
I see it staged the file I require and I can now stage it and commit it.

Comment: If the repo is huge, this still gets all the files

Comment: @evolutionxbox The repo is huge and fetch do take some time, but it does the job and eventually stages the file from the main branch. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: You almost certainly neither need nor want the `--all` option (which, for `git fetch`, means *all remotes* - it has nothing to do with branch names).